# Git checkout doesn't seem to be working

Tags: git, git-workflow

I'm a total git novice but I've been using Git as a way to easily 'upload' a web application to my production server. This is my workflow:-

1. Do some coding locally and commit to `master` branch, when I'm ready
   to release to production I do:-
2. `git checkout production`
3. `git merge
   master`
4. `git push origin production`

Where origin is a **bare repository on the production server**, then I have a post-receive hook which does the following:-

1. `git clone /dir/to/bare_repo /dir/to/production`
2. `cd /dir/to/production_dir`
3. `GIT_DIR=/dir/to/production/.git`
4. `git checkout -f production`

The final checkout command produces the following message:-

> Branch production set up to track remote branch production from origin. Switched
>   to a new branch 'production'

Yet the changes I make locally don't appear in /dir/to/production

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** Just thought I should mention that the changes appear the production branch locally as they should with `git merge master` when on production. It's the checkout on the remote cloned repository that doesn't seem to work

Comment: The seconds item `3. GIT_DIR=...` does not do what you think it does: it does not export the variable to use with `git checkout`

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question, but why not make `master` your production branch and develop your new features on other branches that later get merged to `master`? That avoids an additional checkout after you deploy, and it's a more conventional Git workflow.

Comment: @Brandan: It can be also done by `-b <branch>` to clone.

Comment: @rgvcorley: What do you mean by "if I checkout the production branch locally"? You _did_ check it out! Just before merge with master: `git checkout production`

Comment: @Brandan like I said I'm a total novice with Git, I may well change as you suggest - I would like the workflow to be conventional as someone else will be taking this over eventually. However I don't want to change anything drastic at the moment, Id just like to checkout from my production branch...

Comment: @fork0 yeah what I mean is the changes are correctly on the production branch locally but they don't seem to be when checking out remotely

Comment: @Brandan ok I can't even remember what `GIT_DIR=...` was suppose to do - I had added it after reading on another SO question...

Comment: @rgvcorley: it tells the git commands where to look for Git database. If your script looks like above it has no effect whatsoever. It must be in the same line with `git checkout` to work: `GIT_DIR=... git checkout -f branch`

Comment: @fork0 I see, I've done that, but it makes no difference - I think the git commands look in the current directory for `/.git` by default don't they? So the fact that I've already `cd`'d to `/dir/to/production` should mean I don't need the `GIT_DIR...`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15421/discussion-between-rgvcorley-and-fork0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git archive` and pipe it through your gzip util.

Comment: Yeah, thanks - do you mean `git archive`  - that's what I ended up using. I'm not sure there is an export command? if you change your answer to archive I'll select it :)